# Unlock ssh-agent keychain access prior to terminal opening?

Tags: terminal, keychain

With my SSL certificate passwords stored using ssh-agent I just need to provide a master passphrase to unlock the keychain in the terminal. Generally this isn't an issue, but when the computer restarts I am left typing in the passphrase into each terminal tab. This can be up to 10 tabs, which is fairly annoying.

Is there any way to have the ssh-agent keychain unlocked prior to the terminal tabs opening, so I only need to type it once?

Answer (score 0):

Since first asking this, I have found [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132065/how-do-i-get-ssh-agent-to-work-in-all-terminals) that appears to work for me. I'll provide the essentials here.

Based on the answer and the fact I am using zshrc as shell, Oh My Zsh and that I had been using the [ssh-agent plugin](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/ssh-agent), I first removed the `ssh-agent` plugin from the [plugins declaration](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Plugins).

From there I followed the suggestion of adding the following lines to `~/.profile`:

```sh
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=~/.ssh/ssh-agent.$HOSTNAME.sock
ssh-add -l 2>/dev/null >/dev/null
if [ $? -ge 2 ]; then
  ssh-agent -a "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" >/dev/null
fi
```

The explanation being (from the Unix & Linux [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132065/how-do-i-get-ssh-agent-to-work-in-all-terminals)):

> Do not start ssh-agent from .bashrc or .zshrc, since these files are
> executed by each new interactive shell. The place to start ssh-agent
> is in a session startup file such as .profile or .xsession.

So far this seems to be working for me, though I am tempted to see if the ssh-plugin configuration can be modified for similar behaviour.

Comment: However that commnet re .profile is not relevant for macOS as .profile (if no .bash_profile) is read on the openeing of ever terminal just like .bashrc. Your fix is totally different to that quote as you have put in in .zshrc which is says not to do.

Comment: I meant `~/.profile`, but at the same time I am seeing limitations to my answer, since it is causing issues for my nixos credentials. I'll need to dig a little more.

Comment: Ok then definitely wrong - if you use zsh then it is not read at all - if you use bash it is loaded in the terminal everytime .bashec is if you don't have .bash_profile - if you do have .bash_profile then it is not read. As for nix on macOS it messes up the startup files and you probably have to edit something.